# Updating Dojo store data on client end

Tags: javascript, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

I have a data grid which is bound to a ItemFileReadStore. In my case, I have a "prioritize" column to shift the rows up-down as per user's selection. The prioritization order is stored in DB table. Currently I have achieved it by sending AJAX request on each Up-Down arrow click and getting the updated data in JSON object and reloading the entire data in the data grid.

But I think that's too much of data carrying. what I am looking for is: after updating the data in DB, if the update was successful, I would just pass a success flag to the calling JS method and I would update the data locally in the store at client side. That would make the response faster and will take less network load.

I know it can be done in ExtJS (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Record-set) but not sure how to get in Dojo. I went through the documentation but could not find anything helpful.

Can anyone please guide me thought this?

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier to answer if you define what is your resource behind.
I had an exact problem and solved it with JsonRest together with dgrid.

From your question I have understood that you are sending AJAX requests to a DB and this means that you have (hopefully) a small REST API in between.

If so, I would suggest to switch from ItemFileReadStore to dojo/store/JsonRest which actually does not harm your existing data manipulation architecture but even greatly improves it.

dojo/store/JsonRest will do exactly what you are looking for and even more. Any small change in store will be handled gallantly as you mentioned, without expensive update of entire data.

Sorry if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: This is one of the examples [link](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/master/test/JsonRest.html)

Comment: Or you can use just JsonRest without dgrid [link](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/store/JsonRest.html)